# read first char from var %%i from for iteration

Tags: shell, batch-file

I want to have acces to the first char from the variable in the for iteration.

Here is my code :

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (temp.csv) do (

    set vari = %i% rem >> vari
    echo %vari:~0,1%
)
```

the last echo just write "%" instead of the first charater of the variable. and if I write :

```
echo %vari:~0,2%
```

It's write the whole string that is in %%i.

So My question is :How can I get the first character from the %%i variable?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spaces are important in batch, avoid them before or after equal signs.
The second problem in your code is the fact that percent expansions are expanded when a block is parsed, not when it's executed.
And the expansion of parameters aren't work like `set vari=%i%`, instead you need to use `set vari=%%i`

So you need in this case the delayed expansion for variables.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (temp.csv) do (
    set "vari=%%i"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo !vari:~0,1!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: I just try your code and it's only write : ":~0,1"  when echo is call.

Comment: I try this : setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (temp.csv) do (
    set vari=%i%
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 echo %%i
 echo %vari%
        echo %vari:~0,1%
    endlocal
)
and It's write(for exemple) :
</slide15>
Command ECHO desactivé.
~0,1

Comment: I just copied your line `set vari=%i%`. But now I corrected it to `%%i`

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (temp.csv) do (
    set "vari=%%i"
    call echo %%vari:~0,1%%
)
```